# How do I check the attribute value of a div in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I use the JavaScript code below to get and log the attribute value of a div.
I want to rewrite the JavaScript code using React. When I tried doing the same code in React. I get error: e.path.find is not a function

How The Function Works:

- First,after clicking mealsEl, e.path.find is used to go through all the child elements of meals EL,
- Then it returns the child elements containing the class Name: 'meal-info'
- Then it checks if the child element containing class Name 'meal-info' also has an attribute of 'data-meal-id.
- Then it logs the value of 'data-meal-id'

  ```js
      const mealsEL = document.getElementById('meals')

      mealsEL.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        const mealInfo = e.path.find((item) => {
          console.log(item)
          if (item.classList) {
            return item.classList.contains('meal-info');
          } else {
            return false;
          }
        });
      console.log(mealInfo)
        if (mealInfo) {
          const mealID = mealInfo.getAttribute('data-mealid');
          getMealByID(mealID);
        }
      });
  ```

  ```html
      <div class="container">
         <div id="result-heading"></div>
         <div id="meals" class="meals">
         
         <div class="meal">
             <img class="meal-img" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random" alt=""  style="width:180px; height: 180px;border: solid #000 4px;"/>
               <div class="meal-info" >
          </div>
          </div>
      </div>
       <div id="single-meal"></div>
      </div>
  ```

  ```
  <div id="result-heading"></div>
  <div id="meals" class="meals">

  <div class="meal">
      <img class="meal-img" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random" alt=""  style="width:180px; height: 180px;border: solid #000 4px;"/>
        <div class="meal-info" >
   </div>
   </div>
  ```

  ```js
      const mealsEL = document.getElementById('meals')

      mealsEL.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        const mealInfo = e.path.find((item) => {
          if (item.classList) {
            console.log(item.classList)
            return item.classList.contains("meal-info");
          } else {
            return false;
          }
        });
        // console.log(mealInfo)
        if (mealInfo) {
          const mealID = mealInfo.getAttribute('data-mealid');
          // getMealByID(mealID);
          console.log(mealID)
        } else {
          console.log('no')
        }

      });
  ```

  ```html
      <div id="meals" class="meals">
        <div class="meal">
          <img class="meal-img" src="" alt="">
          <div class="meal-info" data-mealid="75757">
            <h3>Click To Show Data Meal Id</h3>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- When mealsEL is clicked, the function uses e.path.find to check if the mealsEl children element contain a className of 'meal-info' and stores the result in the variable `const meal-info`

      // The second if statement checks if the child element containing className meal-info has an attribute of 'data-mealid'

      // Then the value of data-mealid attribute from the child element is logged to the console
      </div> -->

  // React Code

    const getMealByID = (e) => {
      const NativePath = e.nativeEvent()
      const mealInfo = NativePath.path.find((item) => {
        console.log(mealInfo)
        if (item.classList) {
          return item.classList.contains('meal-info');
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      });
      if (mealInfo) {
        const mealID = mealInfo.getAttribute('data-mealid');
        getMealByID(mealID);
      }
    }

     
         

       
          <div id="meals" className="meals" onClick={getMealByID}>
           
            {meals &&
              meals.map((meal) => {
                const src = meal.strMealThumb;
                const mealID = meal.idMeal;
                const alt = meal.strMeal;
                const index = meal.idMeal;


                // const mealIng = meal.strIngredient1;
                const mealIng = [];

                for (let i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
                  if (meal[`strIngredient${i}`]) {
                    
                    mealIng.push(
                      `${meal[`strIngredient${i}`]} - ${meal[`strMeasure${i}`]}`
                    );
                  } else {
                    break;
                  }
                }

                return (
                  <div className="meal" key={index}>
                    <img className="meal-img" src={src} alt="{alt}" />
                    <div className="meal-info" data-mealid={mealID}>
                      <h3>{alt}</h3>
                    </div>
                    <h2>{mealIng}</h2>
                  </div>
                );
              })}
  ```

Comment: Can you show your React code?

Comment: Okay, I'll do that now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the error because you are calling `getMealByID` with an invalid argument, the function expect an event as argument:

```
if (mealInfo) {
   const mealID = mealInfo.getAttribute('data-mealid');
   getMealByID(mealID); //--> mealID is not an event
}
```

Also I think you can get the mealInfo node using less code:

```
const getMealByID = e => {
   const node = e.target;
   const mealInfo = node.querySelector(".meal-info");
   if (mealInfo) {
     const mealID = mealInfo.getAttribute("data-mealid");
     ...
   }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 // In order to get the data-mealid attribute value from a div
//  by using its parent's element . I had to use 
//  e.target.getAttribute("data-mealid") on a click event from the parents element.


 function App() {

        const getMealInfoAttribute = e => {
                const mealIDData = e.target.getAttribute("data-mealid")
                console.log(mealID)
             };
    
    return (
    <div id="meals" className="meals" onClick={getMealInfoAttribute}>
                <div className="meal" key={index}>
                  <img className="meal-img" src={src} alt="{alt}" />
                  <div className="meal-info" data-mealid={mealID}>
                    <h3>{alt}</h3>
                  </div>
                </div>
              );
    
            
        </div>)
}
```